# How to get all Buttons (or any other type) from Panel?

Tags: winforms, .net-3.5, compact-framework

I would like to get all corresponding type of controls from any ControlCollection. It is important to know, I store some meta data in *Tag* property of controls.
Here is my method for getting back the corresponding T type of controls:

```
public static void GetAllChildControls<T>(Control.ControlCollection root, List<T> list) where T : Control {
  if (list == null)
    list = new List<T>();
  foreach (Control ctl in root) {
    if (ctl.GetType() == typeof(T))
      list.Add((T)ctl);
    if (ctl.Controls.Count > 0)
      GetAllChildControls(ctl.Controls, list);
  }
}
```

The only reason why I writing this post is because I don't get back the value for *Tag*. In VS2008 *(T)ctl* has no evaluable Tag (and ContextMenu as well). It shows "Could not evaluate expression". Otherwise all other things seems to be OK.

**UPDATE**

the code where I'm asking the Tag property:

```
...
List<Button> list = null;
Helper.GetAllChildControls<Button>(master.ChildControls, list);
if (list != null)
  foreach (CounterItem c in counters) {
    Button b = list.Single(e => e.Tag.Equals(c.Name));
                                  ^^^
    if (b == null)
      continue;
    b.SetCounter(c.Value);
  }
...
```

Comment: Post the code where you use the Tag property

Comment: @E-Bat done, post has been updated

Comment: What is the behavior/error that you are getting?

Comment: It is a compile exception? runtime?. BTW, note that the line if (b == null) will never get evaluated as Single linq method will rise an exception if it cannot find a match, maybe you need to change to SingleOrDefault

Comment: I get runtime error "Could not evaluate expression" by evaluating e.Tag. BTW b == null has really no sense...

Answer (score 1):

The way you call the method would never produce any results:

```
List<Button> list = null;
Helper.GetAllChildControls<Button>(master.ChildControls, list);
....
public static void GetAllChildControls<T>(Control.ControlCollection root, List<T> list) where T : Control 
{
    if (list == null)
        list = new List<T>();
```

Since you're not passing the parameter as `ref List<T> list`, the `list` in the scope of the method will be created, but the `list` *in the scope of the caller* will still be `null`.

If I were you I'd make `GetAllChildControls<T>` return a list:

```
public static List<T> GetAllChildControls<T>(Control.ControlCollection root) where ...
```

Comment: Don't think you want it to return List<Button>, what if T is ComboBox?

Comment: I already added _ref_ before list in live code but it has no matter, Tag is still "Could not evaluate expression"...

Comment: @cdkMoose, no chance to be Combobox in this snipets,Button types are filtered out in his generic method

Comment: @E-Bat, true for the second code snippet, but the definition in the first code snippet is generalized to Type T, so inappropriate to define the result as List<Button>